# is It possible to Monitor all the mailbox using Nodejs instead of particular MailBox?

Tags: node.js, imap

I am creating my Own Email Client Application using nodejs.Nodejs will sit between my Client Application and IMAP Server.
I am using node-imap module from Nodejs. It is designed to monitor only one mailbox at a time. But i supposed to monitor all the mailboxes available from IMAP mail Server.

I am using IMAP IDLE concept here. AS per RFC, IDLE only applies to the selected mailbox, thus requiring an additional TCP connection per mailbox. But i want to monitor all the mailboxes without using any additional TCP connection using NOde js Cluster concept simultaneously...

please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. That's what NOTIFY does and I bet the server you're using doesn't support NOTIFY.

Comment: ya correct, gmail and yahoo not supporting right now. is there any alternate solution for this...

Comment: The alternative solutions are a) to use many TCP connections or b) to issue STATUS regularly for the less important mailboxes.

Comment: What about ConditionalStore? is it help full?

Comment: If you use recurrent STATUS, yes, it is.

Comment: Might look at the Trojita or Thunderbird source.

Comment: One more doubt, we have SUBSCRIBE AND UNSUBSCRIBE command in IMAP right? May i know use of those command, what it will do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48363/discussion-between-pyare-and-arnt)